# Background image is not replacing in my css

Tags: css, image, background-image

Present background image is

```
background: url("../img/hero-bg.jpg") top center;
```

I want to replace it, so I tried this:

```
background: url("../img/bg.jpg") top center;
```

The Image: **bg.jpg** is the same folder where **hero-bg.jpg** is.

The image won't be replaced, so that still **hero-bg.jpg** is visible. 
If I inspect the element it showed me this Stylesheet for it:

```
background: url("../img/hero-bg.jpg") top center;
```

Any Idea why?

Comment: probably empty your browsers cache

Comment: what can i do? can you tell me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Dev tools -> Network tab -> Disable cache -> Reload the web-page

[image]